# Trying to deploy friendly-pix Firebase web sample and encountering errors

Tags: javascript, firebase, web

I am trying to deploy the friendly-pix firebase sample which can be found at https://github.com/firebase/friendlypix/tree/master/web and am running into errors after deploying it. Below is a screenshot showing what the console debugger is 
telling me.

[image]

I'm really at a loss for what to do as the error appears to be in the firebase script. I also checked the network tab and nothing is giving a 404 error so all scripts appear to be deployed correctly.

Comment: Were you able to rectify the problem ? I am stuck with the same thing. If you were able to solve the problem, can you guide me ? Thanks.

Comment: Man this was a while ago, but I think I opened an issue on their GitHub for it. Check there and see if you can find it. If not, I'll look for you when I get a chance